# gcloud create-with-container --network-interface flag not supported

Tags: gcloud

I've got the gcloud cli updated to last version, but i cannot run
**gcloud compute instances create-with-container** because the ***--network-interface flag*** seems to be not supported ( but working with **gcloud computes instances create** ). The 2 commands were created from Google Cloud Interface ( Equivalent Code ). 
How to make **gcloud compute instances create-with-container** works with --network-interface flag ?

```bash
## with create-with-container : the --network-interface flag is not working as expected.
gcloud compute instances create-with-container instance-test-dotnet \
    --project=XXXXXX \
    --zone=us-central1-a \
    --machine-type=f1-micro \
    --network-interface=network-tier=PREMIUM,stack-type=IPV4_ONLY,subnet=default \
    --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE \
    --provisioning-model=STANDARD \
    --service-account=XXXXXX \
    --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append \
    --image=projects/cos-cloud/global/images/cos-stable-109-17800-147-22 \
    --boot-disk-size=10GB \
    --boot-disk-type=pd-balanced \
    --boot-disk-device-name=instance-test-dotnet \
    --container-image=us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/learn-415814/mvc-test/mvc-test:latest \
    --container-restart-policy=always \
    --no-shielded-secure-boot \
    --shielded-vtpm \
    --shielded-integrity-monitoring \
    --labels=goog-ec-src=vm_add-gcloud,container-vm=cos-stable-109-17800-147-22

### -> Result : ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create-with-container) argument --network-interface: valid keys are [address, aliases, external-ipv6-address, ... ]
    
## with create-with-container : the --network-interface flag is supported in this case.
gcloud compute instances create instance-test \
    --project=XXXXXX \
    --zone=us-central1-a \
    --machine-type=f1-micro \
    --network-interface=network-tier=PREMIUM,stack-type=IPV4_ONLY,subnet=default \
    --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE \
    --provisioning-model=STANDARD \
    --service-account=XXXXXX \
    --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append \
    --create-disk=auto-delete=yes,boot=yes,device-name=instance-test,image=projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-12-bookworm-v20240213,mode=rw,size=10,type=projects/learn-415814/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-balanced \
    --no-shielded-secure-boot \
    --shielded-vtpm \
    --shielded-integrity-monitoring \
    --labels=goog-ec-src=vm_add-gcloud \
    --reservation-affinity=any

### -> Result : Works, instance is created
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `--network-interface`? Note that `stack-type` is not a supported option for `create-with-container`. Are you trying to enable IPv6 to the container? IIRC, container IPv6 is not supported but I have not verified that recently.

Comment: i'm just converting the google cloud console command to gcloud command with the "Equivalent Code" button, and this process returned my this. the ipv4 only is not important in my case

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Are you trying to say there is a bug in the equivalent command from the Google Cloud Console GUI? Edit your question to clearly describe the issue.

Comment: yes, there is a bug in the equivalent command from the Google Cloud Console GUI ( create a compute engine instance from container image in Artifact Registry ). the process works but the equivalent code is producing an error as described. tell me if you need any additional details.

Comment: To report bugs, use Google's Issue Tracker: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers